# grpc and Intel compiler

Tags: c++, grpc, icc

I would like to use gRPC as a bridge/glue between C++ and Java components (on both Windows and Linux although at the moment I'm more interested in Windows solution) but the main blocker I'm currently facing is lack of support for Intel compiler (I guess mainly due to third party dependencies like abseil for example which don't support it) which is used by some components. Normally I would go through all errors and try to fix them myself but as I'm not C++ expert that may not end up well plus perhaps there is another way to bypass that problem.

What I mean by "bypassing" is strictly speaking I don't have to compile new component with ICC as long as there is another way of plugging my new library/code into existing C++ project (which is compiled with ICC). I know that I'm oversimplifying here (and with C++ it's never that easy) but at the end it should just be a matter of adding another DLL to app dependencies. I read few rather old threads on mixing different C++ compilers and while not recommended it seems doable but suggestions on how to do that seemed like an overkill so I'm wondering whether there is a simpler way of (just) linking and using my library/binary without falling back to COM (perhaps things moved on in recent years and there is a better way of doing it?).

Has anyone managed to do something like that (and separately has anyone managed to get gRPC compiled with ICC - not specifying any versions as this seems to be a problem for a long time)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dlls on windows need special care when it comes to their exposed API. Some libraries prefer not to bother and do not officially support building as a dll.

I know from previous experience that grpc doesn't support building as a dll. You can read about it [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md#windows_a-note-on-building-shared-libs-dlls). It should be possible to compile, but there's an extremely high chance it'll trigger horrible dll heap related bugs.. It's definitely not the way to go for production code

A possible solution, is to statically link grpc into **your own** dll. Make a wrapper that hides any grpc API, compile it all using MSVC, and then use it as dll dependency in your ICC project.

Comment: @GalAnonim: Did you mean to comment on that paragraph you quoted from the answer?

Comment: "A possible solution, is to statically link grpc into your own dll. Make a wrapper that hides any grpc API, compile it all using MSVC, and then use it as dll dependency in your ICC project."

That's exactly what I'm thinking about, ie. I started writing a wrapper code around grpc based service/API which ICC compiled code is going to call. Originally the plan was to compile whole thing with ICC but that's not going to work hence my question (apologies for my complete lack of knowledge on C++ but it's been ages since I've had to work on C++ code and other threads I read got me worried).

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, sorry - I pressed enter too early.

Comment: @GalAnonim so I think you're in the right direction. It should be possible to link with a dll built with a different compiler. What you need to take special care of is what you pass through the dll boundary - e.g. you shouldn't pass an intance of a class created in your exe into your dll(or vice-verse), since the different compilers will very possibly build it differently binary-wise.. I'd create a C-api, and make sure that any c++ code is internal to the dll. Look up ```extern "C"```.

Comment: @GalAnonim If my answer was helpful I'd be happy if you'll accept it. If you have any follow-up questions be my guest

Comment: @theroyn - few other non-related things cropped out so I haven't had a chance to implement/finish it yet but happy to accept your answer for now. I'll definitely ask if I get stuck. Thanks for hints.